# How to build chromium browser for android?

Tags: android, chromium

I am trying to build chromium browser for android by following:
https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/android-build-instructions

when I try to build the browser, I get the following:

ninja -C out/Release chrome_public_apk
ninja: Entering directory `out/Release'
ninja: error: unknown target 'chrome_public_apk'

Has anyone encountered this issue and knows how to solve it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: The target is missing. That  means the documentation doesn't match the "Makefile" equivalent or you haven't setup the build environment completely

Comment: Maybe you can have a look with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36750948/how-to-build-chromium-for-android, it's similar with your problem.