# How to build chromium for Android

Tags: android, chromium

I am trying to build Chromium for Android by following the instructions [here](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/android-build-instructions). When I finally run

```
~/chromium/src$ ninja -C out/Release chrome_public_apk
```

I get this error:

```
ninja: error: unknown target 'chrome_public_apk'
```

It seems that target is not built. In [this link](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/build-instructions-android-webview), it says to run `build/gyp_chromium -DOS=android` before running the ninja command. However, I had followed the instructions for `gn`. What should I be calling in that case?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Run `gn args out/${name}` to set up the build parameters for GN that'll build into `out/${name}` (e.g. `out/ChromeRelease`, don't use `Release` or `Debug` since they'll conflict with GYP). Here's some the parameters I use:

```
    target_os = "android"
    target_cpu = "arm"  # (default)
    is_debug = false  # (set to true for Debug build)
    symbol_level = 1 # 2 includes more symbols useful
                     # for debugging but increase binary size.
                     # 0 strips it down even more.
    is_component_build = true
    is_clang = true
```

Additionally, you'll want to add `target_os = ["android"]` to the .gclient file in your chromium directory and run `gclient sync`.

Comment: How do you build for 'arm' and 'arm64' both in single compilation? I see you `arm` is a default 'target_cpu' but how to compile both/multiple cpu's?

Comment: I'm not aware of a way, I think you'd have to have multiple build configs (i.e. out/ChromeArm and out/ChromeArm64)